# img background error in sass

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

I'm new one in sass technology for now i just study it. And try to make my first project structure. Here is what i have for now:
[sass structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGqku.jpg)

I have  some problem with **_layout.scss** file. This file contains code:

```
#main_middle {
background-image: url("../img/far53.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position:center;
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
}
```

When i try to move this file in **/app/sass/layout** folder and try to use gulp to compile it in css file it show error in css:

```
Cannot resolve file 'file name' 
This inspection checks references to file and directories
```

Same error occurs if i create sass file in layout folder and past code there. In this case, error occurs even before compilation in css. I checked the path to img file in all cases, all is okay. In the way like on screen if I compile all is okay, no errors. And also give a feedback about my sass project structure, if it possible. Sorry if i edit this post little bit wrong, first time asking for help here.

Comment: Can you post the content of your main.scss file to show how you're referencing the partials (_layout.scss, _footer.scss, etc). 

I also noticed there's a typo in your file name - _layou.scss

Comment: Here is the link for main.css file:
https://pastebin.com/eDrV0eDA. 
But there is nothing special. just a list of css code. 
State of #middle_main is from the structure screen.

Comment: No, I wanted the SCSS file, not the outputted CSS. The reason I ask is that it looks like you have a typo in one of your file names.